# How do i find duplicates across a list

Tags: java, arrays, list

I was trying to take in a user ID and check for it against a list to see if it exists already. If it does, then print "ID already exists" if not, then take in the user name and store it in the list.

```
private LinkedList<Person> people = new LinkedList<Person>();

    private void addPerson(){
           int personId = readPersonId();
           Person person = person(personId);
           if (person.hasId){
           System.out.println("ID already exists"); 
           }
          else{
           String s = readName();
           people.add(new Person(personId, s, 2));
          }
        }
```

However my program stops in the first loop for some reason.

Comment: You haven't shown any loops...and what do you mean your program "stops"? Does it hang or give an exception?

Comment: also what is `person.hasId`?

Comment: Consider using Set instead of List. It doesn't allow to contain duplicates.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `private Person person(int id){
        for (Person person : people){
        if (person.hasId(id)){
        return person;
        }
        }
        return null;
    }`

this is the method that returns the person with id otherwise it returns null. The has.id is a boolean containing whether the selected i.d is in the list or not. I should've added this in the OP, but it slipped my mind. Nothing i tried so far has worked though.

Answer (score 0):

go through the list of people you have already and look for anyone with the same id. if there are no matching ones, the go a head and add the new person to the list.

```
private LinkedList<Person> people = new LinkedList<Person>();

private void addPerson(){
    int personId = readPersonId();
    boolean found = false;

    for (Person curr : people) {
        if (curr.getId() == personId){
            System.out.println("ID already exists"); 
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        Person person = person(personId);
        String s = readName();
        people.add(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation helps nobody! Please add an explanation to better this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can dump your arraylist into a set and than compare these 2. If the size of the set is lower than arraylist size, then there are duplicates.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = ...;
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(list);

if(set.size() < list.size()){
    /* There are duplicates in your arrayList */
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help to figure out whether a given id is a duplicate or not.